# Incomprehensible MySQL error in PHP (table doesn't exist, union query)

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm still getting mysql error in my PHP script.

Problematic code:

```
$mquery = mysql_query("SELECT m.`id`, m.`name`, NULL AS `type`, NULL AS `code`, 0 AS `cat` FROM `menu` m UNION ALL SELECT l.`id`, l.`name`, l.`type`, l.`code`, l.`cat` FROM `lines` l UNION ALL SELECT s.`id`, s.`name`, s.`site`, s.`site`, s.`cat` FROM `sites` s ORDER BY `name` ASC");
if(!$mquery) { echo mysql_error(); die(); }
while($mdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($mquery)) { ... }
```

When i put this query into PhpMyAdmin - all is OK, i will get result. When I put this query into MySQL Workbench - all is OK, i will get result.

AND NOW: When I run script with parameter (http://domain/index.php?site=ABC) - ALL IS OK. When I run script without parameter (http://domain/index.php) - I get mysql error on this query: "Table 'test.menu' doesn't exist".

What "test.menu"?! Where is "test"? I don't want any "test", I have no "test" in my query. And why is it related on parameter in url? It's not dynamically generated query. Where is problem?

*Sorry for my english*

Solved, script structure:

```
$mydb = mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db(..., $mydb);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mydb);

function newMenu($db)
{
  $mquery = mysql_query("...", $db);
  if(!$mquery) { echo mysql_error(); die(); }
  while($mdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($mquery) { ... }
}

myMenu($mydb);
```

But what i don't understand is: Why is it working without "$db" when parameter 'site' is in url?

Comment: First of all mysql_* extension is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: I know but it's old and very huge project, it will be very difficult to remake it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your mysql configuration in PHP. I am pretty sure you are using database name as 'test' because you've copied the code from somewhere. Change it to the actual name of your database and it will work.

The second parameter of mysql_query must be a connection variable.

```
 <?php  
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypass") or  
 die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());  
 mysql_select_db("tutorials");  
 $result = mysql_query("select * from tutorials");  
 echo "<h2>Here is a list of the topics:</h2>";  
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
   echo $row['name']."<br />";  
 }  
mysql_close($con);  
?>
```

Comment: Nothing is copied "from somewhere" and no database is named "test".

Comment: Connection code:

mysql_connect("localhost", "lakovna", "--censored--");
mysql_select_db("lakovna") or die("NELZE SE PRIPOJIT K DATABAZI / UNABLE TO CONNECT TO DATABASE");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

Comment: Pass this variable as the second parameter in mysql_query

Comment: I tried it and now I do not understand anything.

$mydb = mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db("...", $mydb);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mydb);

$mquery = mysql_query("...");
if(!$mquery) mysql_error(); --> still the same error

$mydb = mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db("...", $mydb);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mydb);

$mquery = mysql_query("...", $mydb);
if(!$mquery) mysql_error(); --> I get errors: undefined variable: mydb + expects parameter 2 to be resource - on line with mysql_query() - wtf?

Comment: AHA, problem solved.
mysql_query is in function. When I put $mydb into function, it's working.

But what i don't understand is why it is working when parameter site is set.

Answer (score -3):

Could you give full php script? is the database config related to 'site' parameter ?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: No, database config is not related to 'site' parameter. It's static.